# Passing a c library path from a conan package to a source file

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

I'm using Conan to package an old C library.

The library has a loading process that requires you provide the path to a library from inside a .cpp source file. How can the directory to the conan packaged lib be accessed from inside the consuming source?

So the setup is like:

conan package roughly like:

```
ole_c/0.0:
    
    |--include
    
       |-- ole_c_api.h
    
    |--bin
    
       |-- libole_c.so
```

with a consuming:
consumer_main.cpp

Then consumer_main.cpp includes ole_c_api.h and has to call a function passing the path to libole_c.so.

How can you pass that path to consumer_main.cpp?
One possibility is to pass a compile flag -DPATH_TO_OLE_C_LIB= which can then get stringified by a macro inside consumer_main.cpp. How can you access the path to libole_c.so from either inside cmake or in the ole_c packaging conan.py and pass it appropriately?

Comment: C/C++ source files has nothing to that. Build manager will pass information to compiler and linker where header file and library is located. The only thing which should be visible in source code is `#include <ole_c_api.h>`. IMO you should read about build process basics, conan and cmake just provide configuration for that.

Comment: I didn't make the library, and I don't like it, but as best I can tell that's how it seems to work from their documentation. This first lib seems to load a whole host of libs. To paraphrase them:

"When you load the library, you instruct the system to load the shared object file and set all function pointers to their respective values. This is done by calling OLECLoadLibrary. This function exists in two versions :

Use OLECLoadLibraryA if you wish to specify the library path using const char*.
Use OLECLoadLibraryW if you wish to specify the library path using const wchar_t*. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cmake generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) to get the path to a target's library. If you are using conan in `TARGETS` mode then you could do:

```
target_compile_definitions(MyApp PRIVATE PATH_TO_OLE_C_LIB=$<TARGET_FILE:CONAN_PKG::ole_c>)
```

Alternatively you might be able to populate the [`cpp-info.defines`](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/attributes.html#cpp-info) in the conan recipe and make use of the [`package_folder`](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/attributes.html#package-folder) property to get the installed path of the package (I'm not sure how well this will work).

Comment: both strategies work! I like the 2nd since you can keep the definitions contained to the conan package